# How to Share 1 MapView in all Project Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkmapview

I wanted to know if it was possible to share the same `MKMapView` variable in the whole project.
Since creating multiple instances is increasing memory considerably.
As soon as I open a new `view controller` with just a MapView, it adds 50Mb to memory. And when I dismiss that view controller it only drops about 10Mb.

It is possible to free all the memory of the mapview?. Or is it better to create a single MapView variable and be doing removeAnnotations to create annotations... every time change the map view

```
var mapview = MKMapView()
```

When dismiss `viewcontroller` I do this: (I don't know if anything else is needed.)

```
mapView.removeAnnotations(AllAnnotations)
mapView.delegate = nil
mapView.removeFromSuperview()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes creating many items causes memory gets high even if `deinit` is called , so you make 1 global map

```
import MapKit 
let map = MKMapView(frame:CGRect.zero)
```

and when you need to show it in a vc , add it to view with constraints and after leaving remove it

Comment: Thanks!! . I put this map outside of class right? Is secure to be there? I dont know, sorry if question is stupid

Comment: Yes out side of any class , no security worries about this